# Losing float precision when converting dataframe with tuples to excel

Tags: python, pandas, tuples

Here's the dataframe:

```
      0         1        2

A     (0.2,.1)  (.1,.3)   (.4,.5)
B     (0.2,.14) (.1,.3)   (.42,.5)
C     (.5,.12)  (.1,.5)   (.74,.5)
```

When I try to export it to excel using:

```
df.to_excel('hello.xlsx',float_format='%.2f')
```

It shows floating points like .10000000001 - how do I just show up to two decimals? (the precision seems to be lost when you zip two values , that were previously rounded)

Comment: wait i disagree, this one deals with tuples

Comment: im not having trouble without the tuples, but this one hasnt been addressed yet

Comment: or can you help me answer it then lol